# Sharing Global variables in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, global-variables, global

I have 2 files a.py and b.py as follows:

a.py

```
import b.py
Test="abc"
def main(args):
  global Test
  if args.target=="this":
     Test="klm"
  b.fun()
  #rest of the body which I intend to execute only once
  #hence I cannot call main() again
if __name__ == "__main__":
  #some arguments are parsed
  args = parser.parse_args()
  main(args)
```

b.py

```
import a
print a.Test
```

EDIT: Output:

```
python a.py
abc
```

So basically my question is why is the Test variable not getting updated in b.py and how can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much never rely on imported mutable global variables, and ***never*** import a mutable global with a `from` import. This is what happens when you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Added due to question edit:

You need to consider the ordering of the imports execution. Consider these working files.

a.py

```
print("Entering a")
import argparse

import b
Test="abc"
print("Id of Test: ", id(Test))

def main(args):
  global Test
  if args.target=="this":
     Test="klm"
  b.fun()
  #rest of the body which I intend to execute only once
  #hence I cannot call main() again
if __name__ == "__main__":
  #some arguments are parsed
  print('Entering main')
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--target', dest='target', type=str)
  args = parser.parse_args()
  main(args)
```

b.py

```
print("Entering b")
import a
print a.Test

def fun():
    pass
```

The console produces the following:

```
$ python a.py
Entering a
Entering b
Entering a
('Id of Test: ', 40012016L)
abc
('Id of Test: ', 40012016L)
Entering main
```

The problem is, when you import a python module/file, you will immediately execute all the statements in that module. As such, you have a problem with your dependencies (aka imports), because b is importing a before the value of Test is 'corrected' and then immediately acting on this.

Consider two changes. First, introduce a third file `config.py` that contains this configuration information and that b does not import a. Second, move all your statements that require this config in b into functions that are called/bootstrapped by a, as obviously intended.

### Previous answer:

I have a solution demonstrating the issue, by only modifying b.py

```
def fun():  # Added because your main calls this. An error?
    pass

from a import Test, main
import a
print Test    # prints 'abc'
print a.Test  # prints 'abc'
main()
print Test    # prints 'abc'
print a.Test  # prints 'klm'
```

Within the python interpretor, I can produce the following:

```
>>> import b
abc
abc
abc
klm
```

In your code, you create a new variable called `Test` with the command `from a import Test` that points to the original string object. You actually want to access the `Test` variable owned by the module `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood the error in my code, but what I intend to do is not call main() again and make modifications to the "Test" variable based on a argument passed to the main hence I want those modifications to persist whenever I use "Test" in any other file. Is it possible to do so without calling main() again?

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect these questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I think I understood where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

```
import a
a.main()
print a.Test
a.Test = "new Value"
print a.Text
```

You never invoke the main function.  When you import a module, `__name__` is not `"__main__"`, so your main() never runs.  When you run a.py directly it will run main()

Comment: Thanks joel. So is there no way we can modify a global variable inside a.py and use that "updated" variable in b.py, without calling any function? I mean is there any way in python, that we can modify a global variable and its updated value persists when we import it in a different file?

Comment: You should not use globals.  They will get you in trouble.  But you don't need `main()`.  See updated answer

Comment: I understood the error in my code, but what I intend to do is not call main() again and make modifications to the "Test" variable based on a argument passed to the main hence I want those modifications to persist whenever I use "Test" in any other file. Is it possible to do so without calling main() again?

Answer (score 0):

In a.py you run main in the if statement:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Only executes main() if that is the main script. When you import the module all the code in the if block is not run because it is not the main script. To have the main method be called remove the if statement or just call main in b.py.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood the error in my code, but what I intend to do is not call main() again and make modifications to the "Test" variable based on a argument passed to the main hence I want those modifications to persist whenever I use "Test" in any other file. Is it possible to do so without calling main() again?

Comment: As I said you could remove the if statement in the module and it will run main().